# How to redirect in ChildBrowser to a new URL within PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, childbrowser

I would like to redirect the user to another page when a user went to a third-party website for authentication. I'm using childbrowser to open a webpage within the app context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are opening child-browser just for authentication, maybe its better to copy a form into your page and post the results into a hidden iFrame.

If you look into the ChildBrowser javascript you can see that there is a On Change method that you can have a callback when the url changes- this might allow you to capture the change in URL.